# Using select.select with pygame

Tags: python, select, pygame

Hi I'm trying to make a basic pygame client which should be able to send messages while it's running, I'm really unsure on how to connect between select.select and pygame (and I do not want to use threading).
That's my client code and it seems that the select.select line is blocking the pygame window:

```
import pygame
import socket
import select


messages_to_send = []
open_client_sockets = []


def send_waiting_messages(wlist):
    for message in messages_to_send:
        (client_socket, data) = message
        if client_socket in wlist:
            client_socket.send(data)
            messages_to_send.remove(message)


def display(str):

        text = font.render(str, True, (255, 255, 255), (159, 182, 205))
        textRect = text.get_rect()
        textRect.centerx = screen.get_rect().centerx
        textRect.centery = screen.get_rect().centery

        screen.blit(text, textRect)
        pygame.display.update()

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode( (640,480) )
pygame.display.set_caption('Python numbers')
screen.fill((159, 182, 205))

font = pygame.font.Font(None, 17)
num = 0
done = False
my_socket = socket.socket()
my_socket.connect(('127.0.0.1', 57))
while not done:
        display(str(num))
        num += 1
        rlist, wlist, xlist = select.select([my_socket] + open_client_sockets, open_client_sockets, [])
        for current_socket in rlist:
            if current_socket is my_socket:
                (new_socket, address) = my_socket.accept()
                open_client_sockets.append(new_socket)
            else:
                pygame.event.pump()
                keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
                if keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE] is False:
                    open_client_sockets.remove(current_socket)
                    print 'Connection with client closed'
                else:
                    messages_to_send.append((current_socket, 'Hello, '))

        send_waiting_messages(wlist)
```

Comment: Can you use a short timeout with the call to `select`? Then, if a timeout occurs, handle events normally. I can get your code working handling events in a basic fashion after a select timeout, what does your client code look like. A [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would make it easier to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I modified your main loop to include a timeout.

```
while not done:
    display(str(num))
    num += 1
    rlist, wlist, xlist = select.select([my_socket] + open_client_sockets, open_client_sockets, [], 0.1)
    if not rlist: # a timeout occurred
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                print("Exiting!")
                done = True
    else:
        for current_socket in rlist:
            if current_socket is my_socket:
                (new_socket, address) = my_socket.accept()
                open_client_sockets.append(new_socket)
            else:
                keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
                if keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE] is False:
                    open_client_sockets.remove(current_socket)
                    print('Connection with client closed')
                else:  # send Hello on any other key press
                    messages_to_send.append((current_socket, 'Hello, '))
    send_waiting_messages(wlist)
```